# Python 3: ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python-3.x, list, min

I am trying to fix the following error:

> Python 3: ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

```
def get_min(cur_price,price_list):
    min_cost = []    

    for j in price_list:
        if cur_price > j:
            min_cost.append(cur_price - j)

    return min(list(min_cost))


# Complete the minimumLoss function below.
def minimumLoss(price):       

    min_costs = list(range(0))
    for i in range(len(price)):         
        min_costs.append(get_min(price[i], price[i:]))

    return min(min_costs)
```

Comment: I am facing the issue at return min(list(min_cost))

Comment: Have you tried by printing the value that you are passing to the min function?? Seems like you are passing an empty value. Check the initialization of your values.

Comment: `list(range(0))` is the same as `list()`

Comment: get_min() function looked perfect with no issue with indentation. Nevertheless I made that function code inline within minimumloss() method. Issue is resolved. Thanks much for the help.